# Where to put files I want to load with my program in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT where do I put files I want to load into my program? I know I can use the `/test/` directory, but the problem is I have no idea in what context sbt is executing my scala program. From where does it execute so I know how to write a directory string to grab it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on *"I have no idea in what context sbt is executing my scala program."*? I've no idea what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place them under `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` as described in [Directory structure](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Directories.html)